# How can I calculate what sector of the partition an offset resides in?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, sectors

I have an offset (1519748) and I want to calculate which sector of the partion (1) that the offset resides in. How would I calculate this?

Comment: How large are your sectors? (e.g. 512 bytes, 520 bytes, 4K (AF) )?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: 512 bytes. Using Linux to look at an NTFS dd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the answer is

```
                    1519748
  sector number = [ --------] + 1 = 2969
                      512
```

where [x] is the integer part of x.